# Interpretation of the Holm procedure

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, bonferroni

I have used the following code in Stata to calculate the p-values using the Holm method. However, I can't understand what to report and how to interpret these results.

```
*Holm procedure
parmby "reg anderson Icouples ", by(sample) norestore
by sample: qqvalue p, method(holm) qvalue(q)
by sample: list
```

And for this I get:
[image]
[image]

At first I thought we had to compare the p-values with q-values but apparently, that is not it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each "sample" corresponds to a test, and the "q" is the transformed "p"-value to which you can compare to the nominal $\alpha$ level to evaluate overall statistical significance. In each case you have two tests. The Holm procedure begins with the "most significant" (minimum) p-value and multiplies it by the overall number of tests, i.e. 2. The next p-value is divided by the number of tests minus 1, which is untransformed. In each case, you work from "smallest" to "largest" in the untransformed p-values: if the q-value is significant at the nominal alpha level, report that test as significant, and so on for the second test, etc., until at least one test does *not* "meet statistical significance". Only the first example has only one test meeting significance. All others show no significant results for any test.